# urllib can't download certain images

Tags: python, urllib

I'm trying to download images from specific websites, it seems like I can't download them with `urllib`, although the link is valid and is accessible through chrome browser. I'm trying to figure out why it's happening and how to fix it.

These are the errors I get:

```
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Code:

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import os
myPath2 = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\aaa\\test"
filename = "just_a_test"
fullfilename = os.path.join(myPath2, filename)
urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://image.prntscr.com/image/Vje0uwk0Rv6GpEyTTpKJ7g.png", fullfilename + ".png")
```

Comment: Per the error, the web server forbids you to download those images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site is refusing the request because of the user agent, which identifies it as coming from `urllib`. Try changing it to that of a traditional browser, as in the following example:

```
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [
    (
        "User-Agent",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36",
    )
]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

urllib.request.urlretrieve(
    "https://image.prntscr.com/image/Vje0uwk0Rv6GpEyTTpKJ7g.png", fullfilename + ".png"
)
```